# i want to change gradient color according to their theme . dark and light theme

Tags: flutter, colors, gradient, app-themes

```
Container(
gradient :customColors.darkGradient_whiteGradient
)
```

in dark theme i defined the darkGradient with blue  and grey and in  light theme i  defined  whiteGradient with white and grey but when i  change theme color is not changing according  to their  theme (can any one tell  me this is right  way  of doing this or can recommend any other way )

(this code is working when i  am not using gradient color (like in dark theme darkGradient=blue, IN light theme whiteGradeint = white)  but not workin when i am  using
(like in dark theme darkGradient=blue, grey, IN light theme whiteGradeint = white, grey )